# number of zeros to be considered in the correction term

Tags: nt.number-theory

For working out the correction term for the number of primes below "n" ,using Riemann function,how to decide the number of zeros to be taken in to account.Does it depend upon "n"?

Comment: Proofs of the prime number theorem (specifically, of the explicit formula) have quantitative steps where the effect of restricting the zeros to those within $T$ of the real axis is explicitly given in an error term depending on $T$. One can choose $T$ to be a function of your $n$ to answer your question. See Montgomery and Vaughan's book "Multiplicative Number Theory I" or any book that derives the explicit formula.

Answer (score 1):

It must depend on $n$, since a constant number of zeros would yield a continuous error term in the prime number theorem, while $\pi(x)$ is not continuous. Alternatively, the error term is known to oscillate more than the contribution of individual zeros. See also Greg Martin's valuable comment.